# How to get the maximum which n_clusters(param of hdbscan.flat.HDBSCAN_flat()) can specify

Tags: python, hierarchical-clustering

## Question 1

I got a  Warning `UserWarning: HDBSCAN can only compute 3 clusters. Setting n_clusters to 3...` when I  specified param n_clusters=4, using [HDBSCAN_flat()](https://github.com/scikit-learn-contrib/hdbscan/blob/master/notebooks/Flat%20clustering.ipynb). Can I get the `max_eom_clusters` before I specify the param?

## My Try

Actually, max_eom_clusters(max_clusters) is calculated in [flat.py](https://github.com/scikit-learn-contrib/hdbscan/blob/master/hdbscan/flat.py) line 656-657:

```py
654 # With method 'eom', max clusters are produced for epsilon=0,
655     #   as computed by
656 eom_base_clusters = condensed_tree._select_clusters()
657 max_clusters = len(eom_base_clusters)
```

However, I can't use function _select_clusters() in my class because it is protected.

## Question 2

I think we get a best count of clusters when using HDBSCAN().fit(X), but not a maximum of cluster count. So it's not good to use the best count as max_eom_clusters. Am I right?

Answer (score 0):

I can extract the `max_eom_clusters` value from the UserWarning as blow. But I don't think it's a really good solving.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from hdbscan.flat import HDBSCAN_flat
import re

# simulate two dimension data
np.random.seed(0)
data = np.random.rand(100, 2)
plt.scatter(x=data[:, 0], y=data[:, 1])
plt.show()

# get max_eom_clusters by excepting UserWarning which was filtered s error
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('error', category=UserWarning)
try:
    huge_n_clusterer = 999
    clusterer = HDBSCAN_flat(X=data, n_clusters=huge_n_clusterer)
except UserWarning as e:
    numbers = re.findall("[0-9]+", e.args[0])
    max_eom_clusters = eval(numbers[0])
    print(f"max_eom_clusters is {max_eom_clusters}") # max_eom_clusters is 3
```

And this is the simulation data picture:
[A simulation data Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zVFee.png)